# Django ReportLab Multiple Page Using Frame

Tags: python, django, reportlab

I need to print a long string into a pdf using reportlab. The code is as below. The problem is, the code works as long as it is one page, but when the content is too long and need at least 2 pages to accommodate, the longString variable is not printed into the pdf. What should I do to add a line break when the string is too long.

```
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;     filename="somefilename.pdf"'

    # Create the PDF object, using the response object as its "file."
    c = canvas.Canvas(response)

# Draw things on the PDF. Here's where the PDF generation happens.
# See the ReportLab documentation for the full list of functionality.
longString= ""



styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
styleN = styles['Normal']
styleH = styles['Heading1']
story = []
story.append(Paragraph("This is a Heading",styleH))
story.append(Paragraph(longString, styleN))

f = Frame(inch, inch, 7*inch, 10*inch, showBoundary=0)
f.addFromList(story,c)
c.showPage()
c.save()

return response
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this doesn't work is that you are using a `canvas` to build your document on. In order to let platypus add new pages you need to use a document template e.g. `doc = BaseDocTemplate(pdf_file)`. In order to then build your pdf use `doc.build(story)`.

That should fix your issue, as I'm attempting to use the stackoverflow app on my phone for posting this answer I'm not able to give you corrected code but if you run into problems I'm happy to do so.